# Apache Spark Enron DataSet

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to analysis Enron DataSet on apache spark. I want to extract email from and to.
First created and rdd using following function:

```
def utf8_decode_and_filter(rdd):
    def utf_decode(s):
        try:
            return str(s, 'utf-8')
        except:
            pass
    return rdd.map(lambda x: utf_decode(x[1])).filter(lambda x: x != None)
```

Called the above function with spark sequence

```
data = utf8_decode_and_filter(sc.sequenceFile('/user/ufac001/project1920/samples'))
```

When I do:

```
data.collect()
```

I can see data as list of string with email between the employees. I am guessing it's a list of strings

Now to extract triples of email. I wrote following function:

```
def xml_to_emails(s):
    print(s)
    emailed = []

    return s

rdd = data.flatMap(lambda x: xml_to_emails(x)).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
```

My issue is First I cannot extract email because on xml_to_email function print(s) outputs nothing when I run collect on rdd I can print a tuple with letter and a number.

How do I extract emails from this rdd?

Please be nice I am newbie on spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution like this to and use map inside of flatmap

```
import re

def xml_to_emails(s):
    emailed = []
    FromEmail =re.search('From: (.*)\n', s).group(1).replace("\r","")#Can never be null

    #check if 
    fromemail=""
    fromDomain = FromEmail.split('@')[1]
    if "enron" in fromDomain:
        fromemail =FromEmail

    Date = re.search('Date:(.*)',s).group(1).replace("\r","") #can never be null



    ToEmail= re.search('To:(.*)',s).group(1).replace("\r","")#can never be null

    toemail=""
    toDomain = ToEmail.split('@')
    if len(toDomain)>1:
        if "enron" in toDomain[1]:
            toemail =ToEmail


    CCEmail = re.search('Cc:(.*)',s)#can be null
    if CCEmail is not None:
        CCEmail=CCEmail.group(1).replace("\r","")

    BCCEmail = re.search('Bcc:(.*)',s)#can be null

    if BCCEmail is not None:
        BCCEmail=BCCEmail.group(1).replace("\r","")
    return (fromemail,(toemail,CCEmail,BCCEmail),Date)

data = rdd.map(lambda x: xml_to_emails(x))#.map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
```

I was able to extract emails